# No indentation after empty line

Tags: spacing, line-breaking, indentation

Indentation can be selectively suppressed using `\noindent` or completely with the option `parindent=full` to the KOMA document classes. Books (fiction) are usually structured using paragraphs, indented as the LaTeX default. Additionally, greater changes are indicated by an empty line that is followed by a non-indented paragraph, like the first one in a section.

Is there a possibility to insert such a line break into a LaTeX document or automatically omit indentation after empty lines?

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 15):

First a variant of Werner's solution that allows empty lines after `\changebreak`:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\changebreak}{%
  \par
  \vspace{\baselineskip}%
  \changebreak@skippar
}
\def\changebreak@skippar{%
  \@ifnextchar\par{%
    \expandafter\changebreak@skippar\@gobble
  }{%
    \noindent
    \ignorespaces
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-3]
\changebreak
\lipsum[4-6]

\changebreak

\lipsum[7-9]
\end{document}
```

The detection of the empty line quickly fails if there is something
inbetween, a macro definition, an assignment (but comments do not
disturb).

LaTeX has the same problem for its section headers. There it uses macro `\@afterheading` that uses `\everypar` to
get at the start of the next paragraph and undoes the paragraph indent with a `\lastbox` trick, because the paragraph indent is set as box. `\@afterindentfalse` tells the
macro `\@afterheading` that the indent at the next paragraph is not wanted.
The other task of `\@afterheading` to keep the first two lines of the starting paragraph together is here
also welcome.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\changebreak}{%
  \par
  \vspace{\baselineskip}%
  \@afterindentfalse
  \@afterheading
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]
\changebreak
\lipsum[3-4]

\changebreak

\lipsum[5-6]
\changebreak
\typeout{Last changebreak}

\lipsum[7-8]
\end{document}
```

For the case (probably not likely) that it should be avoided that the break hits a page break,
then the following prevents a page break at the break. And if the
previous paragraph is not yet finished, a last lonely line could also be forbidden.
LaTeX's `\@afterheading` tries the same with the next two lines.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum}
% Option `nopar' suppresses the
% paragraph ends in lipsum paragraphs

\makeatletter
\newcount\chgbrk@widowpenalty
\newcommand*{\changebreak}{%
  % If we are happy and the previous paragraph
  % is not yet finished, we can change
  % the widowpenalty to prevent a previous
  % lonely line.
  \chgbrk@widowpenalty\widowpenalty
  \widowpenalty\@M
  \par
  \widowpenalty\chgbrk@widowpenalty
  \nobreak
  \vspace{\baselineskip}%
  \@afterindentfalse
  \@afterheading
}
\makeatother

%\setlength{\textheight}{\baselineskip}% stress test

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\lipsum[2]
\changebreak
\lipsum[3]

\lipsum[4]

\changebreak

\lipsum[5]

\lipsum[6]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 10):

I would suggest defining a command to do this, for two reasons:

1. This might be done in an ad-hoc fashion; and
2. LaTeX interprets an empty line as a paragraph break anyway, so it may be difficult to construct something that (say) counts the number of blank lines in order to produce a "change break".

My suggestion would be something like `\changebreak` that is similar to `\bigskip`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\def\changebreak{\par\vspace{\baselineskip}\noindent}
\showthe\baselineskip
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-3]
\changebreak
\lipsum[4-10]
\end{document}
```

The traditional `\bigskip` inserts `\bigskipamount` which is fixed at `12pt plus 4pt minus 4pt`. I've modified that to use `\baselineskip` since you're after an empty line. `\noindent` is automatically inserted to remove the indentation in the subsequent paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

The `memoir` class (of course) offers a good selection of 'anonymous' breaks.  The simplest, `\plainbreak{<num>}` produces a gap of `<num> * \baselineskip` and then suppresses indentation of the next line (while the starred version *does* indent the next line:

```
\newcommand{\fancybreak}{\@ifstar{\@sfbreak}{\@fbreak}}
\newcommand{\@fbreak}[1]{\par
  \penalty -100
  \noindent\parbox{\linewidth}{\centering #1}%%\null
  \par
  \@afterindentfalse
  \@afterheading}
\newcommand{\@sfbreak}[1]{\par
  \penalty -100
  \noindent\parbox{\linewidth}{\centering #1}%%\null
\par                                                 
  \@afterindenttrue
  \@afterheading}
```

There are several other related commands, some of these will print arbitrary symbols or text (`\fancybreak`), others will give a plain or fancy break depending on whether they appear near the top or bottom of a page (`\plainfancybreak` and `\pfbreak`).  If you are interested, consult the `memoir` manual; and note that the code for these commands are easily 'lifted' from `memoir.cls` if you can't use `memoir` itself for some reason.  (As the above example hopefully shows, although I did remove some comments.)