# Customizing Memoir Class's \fancybreak

Tags: spacing, line-breaking, indentation

In response to [No indentation after empty line](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/65415/48787) @jon supplied the following `\fancybreak` macro lifted from `memoir.cls`:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\fancybreak}{\@ifstar{\@sfbreak}{\@fbreak}}
\newcommand{\@fbreak}[1]{\par
  \penalty -100
  \noindent\parbox{\linewidth}{\centering #1}%%\null
  \par
  \@afterindentfalse
  \@afterheading}
\newcommand{\@sfbreak}[1]{\par
  \penalty -100
  \noindent\parbox{\linewidth}{\centering #1}%%\null
\par
  \@afterindenttrue
  \@afterheading}
\makeatother
```

However, if this happens to at the bottom of the page in the PDF output, the paragraph starting at the next page receives an extra top-vertical space. Is it possible to customize the macro to avoid that behavior?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage[paperwidth=5in,paperheight=7.5in, margin=0.7in]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{libertine}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\fancybreak}{\@ifstar{\@sfbreak}{\@fbreak}}
\newcommand{\@fbreak}[1]{\par
  \penalty -100
  \noindent\parbox{\linewidth}{\centering #1}%%\null
  \par
  \@afterindentfalse
  \@afterheading}
\newcommand{\@sfbreak}[1]{\par
  \penalty -100
  \noindent\parbox{\linewidth}{\centering #1}%%\null
\par
  \@afterindenttrue
  \@afterheading}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, est alia eirmod no, at has graecis molestie luptatum. Menandri maluisset usu in. Vim cu ceteros luptatum, in mel doming equidem docendi. Timeam volutpat vix ad, vidit albucius duo ne, sed cibo probo ex. No sit meis novum, mel ullum nonumy et, pri an agam eirmod doctus.

Sale apeirian eloquentiam mei ex. Propriae tacimates senserit id per, doming accumsan cum id, omnium scripserit mei eu. Sea pertinacia voluptatibus ex. In audiam menandri conceptam ius, ex mel nullam nemore facilisi, nec ut democritum scripserit. Similique adolescens ius et. Tritani epicurei vel id, usu at salutandi erroribus.

Mel affert regione intellegam ut, etiam minim eos ad. Sit ex malorum persius facilis, et alia sententiae efficiantur usu. Ad sit assueverit reformidans. Augue labore ea cum, ad tamquam antiopam imperdiet ius. Impedit epicurei pro te, sensibus contentiones id eam.

Eam voluptatum appellantur instructior ad, at usu soluta dignissim reprimique, eam no vitae scaevola deterruisset. Id tation consetetur voluptatibus sit, eos eius laudem cu, tibique adipisci his id. Delenit accusam lucilius ea vel, virtute phaedrum concludaturque cu sit. Est te harum mandamus disputando. Nam minim mazim et. In apeirian explicari eam.

Ad vis tibique copiosae tractatos. Purto reque doming sed ad, mutat abhorreant et usu. Tota apeirian dignissim eum ut, pri dicta legimus reprimique ne. Eu has rebum soluta. Liber recteque philosophia et vix, ex salutatus pertinacia concludaturque duo, cu mea utinam aeterno signiferumque.

An aliquam salutatus duo, an qui epicurei persecuti, duis dissentias ad pri. Integre mnesarchum ad est. In pro nemore torquatos. Altera feugiat nusquam te vim, nam et dicta decore consul. Eu ornatus eleifend has, at fabulas menandri vel, cu volutpat constituam pro.

Eam aeterno discere in, ea dicant expetendis repudiandae vim, an usu iudico docendi explicari. Eam iudico omnium volumus an. Quem ullamcorper sit ea, et dolorum noluisse philosophia est. Ne enim meis ignota mei, ex decore deleniti ullamcorper.

\fancybreak

Perfecto atomorum voluptaria eu mea, cum ut solum clita quaerendum. Ne quo offendit oportere, pro eu ignota habemus, solum ludus no ius. Per eu illud populo ancillae, ei vix meliore blandit, ei qui malorum aliquando consequuntur. Bonorum mentitum vim cu. Sed ne tation latine.

Viris tibique signiferumque ne sit. Dissentiunt vituperatoribus vim te, ea facete imperdiet usu. Ea bonorum delicata qualisque usu, munere doming ius ex. Te mei dolores lucilius. In sea labores persecuti voluptatibus, ea choro partem referrentur pro, no utamur delicatissimi necessitatibus sit. Qui ad vivendo sapientem, enim illud sensibus ea duo.

Eam ex alia ignota moderatius, ea tota oratio reprimique mei, sed an hinc laudem. Eu consul laudem nec. Quas tibique maiestatis est an. Sea no wisi quaestio.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you concoct a minimal example?

Comment: @egreg Concocted.

Comment: I see no usage of `\fancybreak`

Comment: @egreg Sorry. Added. If you remove `fancybreak` and add ``\noindent` to the paragraph starting thereafter (“Perfecto”), you will notice the added vertical space.

Comment: You just want blank space, don't you?

Comment: Yes, but if it happens to be at the end of the page in the PDF output, I do not want extra vertical top space added on the next page. (I would think nobody would want that.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\fancybreak` command as defined in the code wants an argument. In your usage the argument turns out to be `\par` (because of the empty line), which produces

```
\noindent\parbox{\linewidth}{\centering\par}
```

and therefore a paragraph (with nothing in it except for the `\noindent`.

You want just space, so you can define

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\novelbreak}{%
  \par\penalty-100\bigskip
  \@afterindentfalse\@afterheading
}
\makeatother
```

Adjust the spacing to suit; here I used `\bigskip`; you might want

```
\vspace{2\baselineskip}
```

or similar. Add stretch and shrink components if you don't use an integral number of lines.

Full example:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage[paperwidth=5in,paperheight=7.5in, margin=0.7in,heightrounded]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{libertine}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\novelbreak}{%
  \par\penalty-100\bigskip
  \@afterindentfalse\@afterheading
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, est alia eirmod no, at has graecis
molestie luptatum. Menandri maluisset usu in. Vim cu ceteros 
luptatum, in mel doming equidem docendi. Timeam volutpat vix ad, 
vidit albucius duo ne, sed cibo probo ex. No sit meis novum, mel 
ullum nonumy et, pri an agam eirmod doctus.

Sale apeirian eloquentiam mei ex. Propriae tacimates senserit id 
per, doming accumsan cum id, omnium scripserit mei eu. Sea pertinacia 
voluptatibus ex. In audiam menandri conceptam ius, ex mel nullam 
nemore facilisi, nec ut democritum scripserit. Similique adolescens 
ius et. Tritani epicurei vel id, usu at salutandi erroribus.

\novelbreak

Mel affert regione intellegam ut, etiam minim eos ad. Sit ex malorum 
persius facilis, et alia sententiae efficiantur usu. Ad sit assueverit 
reformidans. Augue labore ea cum, ad tamquam antiopam imperdiet ius. 
Impedit epicurei pro te, sensibus contentiones id eam.

Eam voluptatum appellantur instructior ad, at usu soluta dignissim 
reprimique, eam no vitae scaevola deterruisset. Id tation consetetur 
voluptatibus sit, eos eius laudem cu, tibique adipisci his id. Delenit 
accusam lucilius ea vel, virtute phaedrum concludaturque cu sit. 
Est te harum mandamus disputando. Nam minim mazim et. In apeirian 
explicari eam.

Ad vis tibique copiosae tractatos. Purto reque doming sed ad, mutat 
abhorreant et usu. Tota apeirian dignissim eum ut, pri dicta legimus 
reprimique ne. Eu has rebum soluta. Liber recteque philosophia et vix, 
ex salutatus pertinacia concludaturque duo, cu mea utinam aeterno signiferumque.

An aliquam salutatus duo, an qui epicurei persecuti, duis dissentias 
ad pri. Integre mnesarchum ad est. In pro nemore torquatos. Altera 
feugiat nusquam te vim, nam et dicta decore consul. Eu ornatus 
eleifend has, at fabulas menandri vel, cu volutpat constituam pro.

Eam aeterno discere in, ea dicant expetendis repudiandae vim, 
an usu iudico docendi explicari. Eam iudico omnium volumus an. 
Quem ullamcorper sit ea, et dolorum noluisse philosophia est. 
Ne enim meis ignota mei, ex decore deleniti ullamcorper.

\novelbreak

Perfecto atomorum voluptaria eu mea, cum ut solum clita 
quaerendum. Ne quo offendit oportere, pro eu ignota habemus, solum 
ludus no ius. Per eu illud populo ancillae, ei vix meliore blandit, 
ei qui malorum aliquando consequuntur. Bonorum mentitum vim cu. Sed 
ne tation latine.

Viris tibique signiferumque ne sit. Dissentiunt vituperatoribus vim 
te, ea facete imperdiet usu. Ea bonorum delicata qualisque usu, 
munere doming ius ex. Te mei dolores lucilius. In sea labores 
persecuti voluptatibus, ea choro partem referrentur pro, no 
utamur delicatissimi necessitatibus sit. Qui ad vivendo sapientem, 
enim illud sensibus ea duo.

Eam ex alia ignota moderatius, ea tota oratio reprimique mei, sed 
an hinc laudem. Eu consul laudem nec. Quas tibique maiestatis est 
an. Sea no wisi quaestio.
\end{document}
```

[image]